# Question RE Safety Report ID

Tags: openfda

I'm seeing the following in the drug event endpoint:

[image]

On a "conceptual" level, it would appear that these are the same person, however, they appear in the drug event endpoint repeatedly, so I'm trying to gain a better understanding, given that openFDA only shows the most recent version. Is this an artifact of some sort of reporting error? How many individual reports are represented above?

Answer (score 0):

Those are all individual reports as submitted by the manufacturer to the FDA (as evidenced by the unqiue `safetyreportid` values); however, at the same time they are all duplicates of one another (as evidenced by the `reportduplicate` field of those records and also matching patient demographics).

In other words, your conclusion of a reporting error is very likely correct: the manufacturer appears to have submitted multiple reports in response to a single adverse event.